# How to programmatically identify Quicktime player is recording the ios device screen when device is connected to mac?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad, quicktime

I want to trigger a alert in a ios app when the ios device screen is captured using quicktime player.

Please guide me if there is a way to detect this.

Comment: Unlikely.  This is not something apps need to know about, your requirement not-withstanding.

Comment: @avi, I have a drm protected video playing in my app so I want to display an alert saying stop recording.

Comment: Well, I really wants to capture your video than you can't stop me doing so. There's just lots of way to do so, I can do it by capturing a video from my other phone as well. But some how, I am not seeing any visibility in your problem. However, to add more lights on your question, this is something that you can't detect with iOS. I have not idea about jailbreak devices.